# Recursive loop stopping after a short time

Tags: lua, computercraft

Lua in ComputerCraft 1.5

This seems to work but the recursive loops is breaking after 4 or 5 times running.

Cannot seem to see why.

Am i doing something incredibly wrong here?
[Full Code](http://pastebin.com/L67UVkGC)

---

**Snippet for the loop:**

```
x = 1

function loop()
 if x > 0 then
  getTarg()
  derp1()
  sleep(2.9)
  monInit()
  loop()
 end
end

loop()
```

Comment: Well it will eventually overflow your stack, though not after 5 times.

Comment: `x` may clash with another global, try changing the condition to `if true then ...`.

Comment: try change to `return loop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are not even using the X var... so why don't you try this... this is a more effective way to keep doing the same thing over and over

```
while true do
    getTarg()
    derp1()
    sleep(2.9)
    monInit()
end
```